# how to remove default user authentication from unisharp file manager laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Please help me about laravel unisharp file manager Actually I want to disable or change the default Authentication of unisharp file manager 
Because i want only admin auth not default User Auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in config/lfm.php set 'middlewares' => [],

for more details
https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/issues/162